# Spring Integration WS Outbound gateway SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, spring-integration

I am using spring integration(4.0.5.RELEASE). Trying to configure keystore to be used to sign outgoing requests. Though I have set my keystore using the environment variable -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore, I can see the below error in my SSL logs

```
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client 
authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
```

Server is sending the right certificate as part of ECDH ServerKeyExchange

The same keystore is working fine, if I use RestTemplate to invoke the service. Please let me know if there is anything else that we need to take care while using int-ws:outbound-gateway

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to investigate really Spring WS subject on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/#security ?

I somehow believe that there is nothing to do from the Spring Integration perspective.

Pay attention there to the `KeyStoreFactoryBean`:

```
<bean id="keyStore" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean">
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="location" value="classpath:org/springframework/ws/soap/security/xwss/test-keystore.jks"/>
</bean>
```

and how to use it with the `KeyStoreCallbackHandler`.